# Espresso testing on Android API 28 emulator click issue

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso

This is only on Android devices with api level 28.
trying to match a text after clicking the spinner fails.

Two approaches, one looking for a window that is not the activity, the second is looking for popup menu:

```
...
    // Look for text "Green" in the menu
    onView(withId(getFieldId(COLOR_ID))).perform(click());
    onView(withText("Green"))
            .inRoot(withDecorView(not(is(rule.getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView())))) // Look for popup menu
            .perform(click());

    // Second spinner, Look for the text "Medium"
    onView(withId(getFieldId(SIZE_ID))).perform(click());
    onView(withText("Medium")).inRoot(RootMatchers.isPlatformPopup()).perform(click());
...
```

Both are working fine with devices API <=27

Any idea why this is not working on 28? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by updating build tools version to 28.0.2 (was 28.0.1) and replaced all android support libraries to use [androidx](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/androidx-overview)